# Access violation with TDictionary.Add

Tags: delphi

**Anyone know why I am getting an access violation with the following**:

```
  unit TestForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Generics.Collections, Vcl.Grids,
  Vcl.ValEdit;

type

  TClientThing = class
  private
    iCDic: TDictionary<string, string>;
  published
    property Dic: TDictionary<string, string> read iCDic write iCDic;

  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    vleHeader: TValueListEditor;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
    ClientThing: TClientThing;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  vCustomParamKey: string;
  vCustomValueKey: string;
  J: integer;

begin

  with ClientThing do
  begin

    // Get the header params from the config and list edit...
    for J := 0 to vleHeader.RowCount - 1 do
    begin
      vCustomParamKey := vleHeader.Cells[0, J];
      vCustomValueKey := vleHeader.Cells[1, J];
      Dic.Add(vCustomParamKey, vCustomValueKey);

    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

The Access violation is at the Dic.Add line. The exception is:

[image]

I have been up all night and so have probably missed something. The TValueListEditor contents are (code editor view):

```
X-Application=g9V0rB9a3J5UF8
X-Authentication=kQNvuuimr0yMtEYZtXAZntTScPlvjecEAGtvbnNIU=
JSONRpc=2.0
```

Comment: What's the error message? How about a complete program?

Comment: You don't appear to instantiate anything. And why did you choose the name `TClientThing`.

Comment: Do you mean like ClientThing := TClientThing.Create; ?
No reason - just any name. It is just a test object...
I could see that the value was nil, but thought that the generic would be assigned when the form was initialised...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form never assigns a value to `ClientThing`, so it's still `nil`. Assign it a value, and then assign a value to `iCDic`. You should have been able to detect this problem when you stepped through the code with the debugger.

Comment: Do you mean like ClientThing := TClientThing.Create; ?

Comment: Ah. You mean this: Dictionary := TDictionary<string, string>.Create

Comment: I said you need to create both.

Comment: And you are doubly awesome. Thanks Rob.